# How do I iterate though an array and do actions based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

My goal is the following:

> Create a loop that compares the array of numbers provided, for the number 28.
> Log `over`, if it is greater than 28, and `under` if it is less than 28.
> Don't log anything if it is equal to 28.

Expected output:

```
2 is under
40 is over 
31 is over
```

This is my code currently; I feel like I am so close, but I'm not sure.

```js
var rando_array = [2, 40, 31, 29, 9, 12, 41, 90];
rando_array.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < var rando_array.length; i++) {
    var Its;

    if (i > 28) {
        Its = "over";
    } else if (i < 28) {
        Its = "under";
    }

    console.log(rando_array[i] + "Its");
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Here are you problems: 1) Your array is called `rando_array` not `over_under_array`. 2) Your variable called `Its` is never used. 3) You will redeclare `Its` every iteration. 4) If you remove the quotes from `"Its"` you would still print incorrectly, as it would display as `2Its`. To solve this: Remove `var Its` and replace the `Its = "over"` with `console.log(over_under_array[i] + 'is over')`. Do the same with `under`. Then rename `rando_array` to `over_under_array`.

Comment: thank you so much I figured it out. Sorry my code and question was allover the place and confusing. But I definitely got it, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted to loop though the array, this solution uses a for-loop.

The same result could be achieved using forEach , maps etc...

```js
let rando_array = [2, 40, 31, 29, 9, 12, 41, 90];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rando_array.length; i++) {
      if (rando_array[i] > 28) {
        console.log(rando_array[i] + " is over")
      } else if (rando_array[i] === 28) {
        // Do nothing
        /* Uncomment to log eqaul
        console.log(rando_array[i] + " is equal")
        */
      } else {
        console.log(rando_array[i] + " is under")
      }
    };
```

Comment: This is the better of the two approaches, though it's not strictly true: OP only wants to show `over` or `under`, and mentioned nothing for if the value is an exact match.

Comment: thank you for helping. Code is still not working but thank you.

Comment: @labirtukey got it man I see u updated your question ! Answer incoming on 5 min

Comment: @labirtukey Check Out the updated answer it will definitely solve the problems

Comment: thank you so much I figured it out. Sorry my code and question was allover the place. But I definitely got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [2, 40, 31, 29, 9, 12, 41, 90]
const max_value = 28

arr.filter(item => item > max_value).forEach(number => {
        // console logs if num is greater than 28
        console.log(number)
    })
```

Comment: Why would you `filter` the array? This is completely the _wrong_ approach, OP only wants to log `over` or `under` depending on the value of each element.

Comment: thank you for helping. I still don't get it but thank you.